# Angular 2+: Given a component instance, tell what properties are injected

Tags: angular

Given a component instance acquired via `ng.probe` or just `console.log(this)` within the component, I want to know what properties are injected via construtor and what properties are user defined inside component.

**Example**: In following code snippet:

**User defined properties inside component:**

1. title
2. input1

**Injected Properties:**

1. serverService
2. activatedRoute

**Code snippet**

```
@Component({

})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ng-bubble-elements';
  @Input() set input1(val){

  }
  constructor(private serverService:ServerService, private activetedRoute: ActivetedRoute){
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

"Injected properties", as you call them, are actually just variables that are written with a shortcut.

The real syntax would be

```
constructor(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
```

This means that unless you add them to an array or something, you can't differentiate them.

#### EDIT

Miunderstood the question.

You can use the injector to get the providers, but you will get them at module level. You will get **all** the providers, and you have to use private properties to do so (hence the array notation)

```
constructor(injector: Injector) {
  console.log(injector['view']['root']['ngModule']['_providers']);
}
```

Comment: But then again, [you should explain your issue instead of asking for advice on a solution you think is the right one](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: This question is not about typescript. Its about angular. These dependencies are injected by injector (DI). All I want to know is, do these injected members have something in common so that you can tell that they were injected via DI? Maybe some ancestor or some property? I hope its clear.

Comment: This kinda answers the question...but i will wait for some better solution. thanks.